# Using Selenium in Python to enter Login Information to Instagram

Tags: python, selenium, instagram

Does anybody know how to automate the login to Instagram using python. I am able to login in other sites, but Instagram just won't work.

I used this code:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name='username']')
element.send_keys('my username')
```

Where is my error?

Comment: I presume that this is using Selenium, since you're using [`find_element_by_xpath()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath) in your code. If so, you should [tag your post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) to indicate this.

Comment: This should output an error (which in turn should tell you what's wrong, namely your usage of quotation marks)

Comment: It's says can't find the element.

Answer (score 6):

The username field is contained in an `<iframe>`.  Selenium can only access objects in the current frame.  You'll need to use `switch_to.frame()` in order to access the content you want to interact with:

```
frame = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe.hiFrame")
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
```

When you're finished in the `<iframe>`, you'll need to switch back out, using `switch_to.default_content()`:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this code, hope this works !

```
from selenium import webdriver

username = "Your Username"
password = "Your Password"

getdriver = ("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(getdriver)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(.,'Log in')]").click()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a time.sleep(timeOutInSeconds) after getting the driver and before you query for elements, example:

```
import time

....
....

driver.get(URL)

time.sleep(3)

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
element.send_keys('my username')
```

It could be that your internet connection is slow and the login form is not loaded, immediately after the driver opens the website.

Answer (score 2):

Put the following code login to instagram using selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
drv= webdriver.Chrome()
drv.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher')
drv.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys('your_username_here')
drv.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys('your_password_here') 
drv.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(u'\ue007')
```

Answer (score 1):

Watch your grammar.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
```

Comment: @JackSparrow Say *what*'s not working, we can't see your monitor screen.

Comment: I use this code: http://prntscr.com/60z8ag and this is error: http://prntscr.com/60z8zq

Comment: Please add all relevant information to your *original question* in the form of a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Pasting the code here is preferred over linking to off-site resources such as image hosts.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

username = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
password = driver.find_element_by_name("password")

username.send_keys("YOUR USERNAME")
password.send_keys("YOUR PASSWORD")

password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```